# Criar "desenhos" com windows API

Tags: c++, gui

Olá, preciso de ajuda com a API do windows no que toca na manipulação de "desenhos". O meu problema é que se redimensionar ou minimizar a janela desaparece tudo o que tinha sido imprimido na consola. Isto é o que já consegui fazer em relação a este assunto:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.ignore();
    //Get a console handle
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    //Get a handle to device context
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    //Choose any color
    COLORREF COLOR= RGB(255,255,255);
    HPEN hBluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, COLOR);
    HGDIOBJ hPen = SelectObject(mydc, hBluePen);

    //Lines
    MoveToEx(mydc, 10, 40, NULL);
    LineTo(mydc, 44, 10);
    LineTo(mydc, 78, 40);

    //Rectangles
    cin.ignore();
    Rectangle(mydc, 16, 36, 72, 70);
    Rectangle(mydc, 60, 80, 80, 90);

    //Elipse
    cin.ignore();
    Ellipse(mydc, 40, 55, 48, 65);

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Isto desenha 5 objetos, duas retas, dois retângulos e uma elipse.

EDIT:

Eu tentei fazer uma abordagem com *WindowProc* mas também sem sucesso. Deixo o código abaixo:

```
        LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
            switch (message) {
                case WM_PAINT:
                    cout << "text";
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           }
      }
```

Comment: Basicamente você tem que fazer o *repaint* toda vez que a visibilidade da janela ocorre. O Windows fica o tempo todo mandando mensagens para sua aplicação indicando que algo ocorreu e que provavelmente você vai querer fazer algo, como redesenhar a tela. Ou seja, é um sistema de eventos. Pesquise por `WNDPROC`. http://keithditch.powweb.com/Games/html/wndproc.html, http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/window_click.html e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx. Isto te ajuda? Resolve a questão?

Comment: Olá, eu já tinha tentado fazer algo deste género mas sem sucesso, mas obrigado na mesma pelos links. Vou colocar essa tentativa na pergunta.

Comment: No WM_PAINT não é pra fazer cout... é pra por o código (ou chamar a função) que desenha!

Comment: @Bacco Só coloquei o cout para ver se o WM_PAINT era chamado e não está a ser chamado

Comment: E você associou o callback na criação da janela? Não basta criar a função, precisa apontar ela como responsável pelas mensagens https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Bacco E como faço isso? Eu não percebi como é que fazem no link indicado.

Comment: Eu recomendo usar alguma API gráfica multiplataforma, se você usar o Windows api, vai dar problema caso você queira portar seu programa pra outra plataforma. (Eu acho até mais fácil desenhar em QT)

Comment: @silas333 Mas por enquanto eu só preciso que funcione para windows, mas obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Alguém me podia fornecer um exemplo? Ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, eu criei uma função recursiva chamada Redraw, que força a atualização da tela a cada 50 milissegundos, veja se resolve o seu problema

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void Redraw(HDC mydc);


int main() {
    //Get a console handle
    HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
    //Get a handle to device context
    HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);

    //Choose any color
    COLORREF COLOR = RGB(255, 255, 255);
    HPEN hBluePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, COLOR);
    HGDIOBJ hPen = SelectObject(mydc, hBluePen);

    Redraw(mydc);

    ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
    cin.ignore();
    return 1;
}

void Redraw(HDC mydc)
{
    //Lines
    MoveToEx(mydc, 10, 40, NULL);
    LineTo(mydc, 44, 10);
    LineTo(mydc, 78, 40);

    //Rectangles
    Rectangle(mydc, 16, 36, 72, 70);
    Rectangle(mydc, 60, 80, 80, 90);

    //Elipse
    Ellipse(mydc, 40, 55, 48, 65);
    Sleep(50);
    Redraw(mydc);
}
```